# How to handle a feature (x1) with huge sample space for linear regression ? (n(x1) >> n(x2,x3,....))

Tags: regression, pca, unbalanced-classes

I have a regression problem to solve, comprising of approx 2000 data points.

I have some 7-8 features, but one of the feature has a huge sample space, meaning When I one hot encode this Feature, it generates 6000 columns.

Overall I have 2000 * (6000 + 7) data set.

Upon trying to reduce (2000 * 6000 ) dataset using PCA, it gets reduced to 2000 * 1500 ( capturing 0.8 variance ).

But still one feature represented by 1500 columns and other 7 features represented by 7 columns, creates a huge imbalance.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the other 7 features are continuous or binary, and this 8th feature is categorical with 6000 different categories - otherwise one hot encoding only it wouldn't make sense.

What you can do, if you have some prior knowledge, is aggregate some of these 6000 categories together. It depends on your data, but there might be a meaningful way to make the categories less granular.

PCA is not a bad approach, and so are univariate feature selection techniques, Lasso regression and more.

To determine the amount of features you want to get from these 6000, you can run cross validation, training the model each time with a different number of features, and see what achieves the best results. But if you only have 2000 points, you would probably want to use less than 1500 features anyway, see https://medium.com/@jennifer.zzz/more-features-than-data-points-in-linear-regression-5bcabba6883e and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality